# Fixing yahoo pipes infinite loop

Tags: twitter, yahoo-pipes

Just started playing with yahoo pipes with twitter for an auto-retweet. For some reason I keep getting an infinite loop. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Here is my pipe:

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=ef6d2f2022a9e560484dc69b12fd4a22

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you can't fetch a search.twitter.com feed directly in Pipes, so you have to wrap it in a YQL call.

The following pipe should do what you want. Searches all tweets that are not retweets and returns the unique authors prepended with '@'.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=a4875d5a0e37176df65806d2896b1ad0